# Will Upgrading to 22.04 Automatically Switch to Wayland?

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, 22.04, wayland

Once in-place upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04 comes out (in the next point release, 22.04.1), I will upgrade in-place and *not* performing a fresh install.

I would like to know if this upgrade will make the switch to Wayland automatically or if I'll have to do some stuff to make the switch since I'm doing an in-place upgrade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes it will

I was in the same boat, ran 20.04 and waited for for 22.04.1. Now that I have upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04.1, I have updated this answer.

## In 20.04

**Wayland is already available in 20.04 LTS, though not default.**

You can switch between Xorg and Wayland at the login screen after clicking on your name, then clicking on the gear icon at the bottom right corner of the password prompt screen.

## In 22.04

Wayland is the **default for new installations** (as well as for upgrades from 20.04).

In the past, I have never seen Ubuntu change any configuration you have chosen after an upgrade to a newer version. For example, when I upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04 it didn't even change my desktop wallpaper to the default 20.04 wallpaper.

It looks like upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 changes the default display protocol from Xorg to Wayland.

## Switch back to Xorg

You can always switch back to Xorg by the same gear icon in the login -> password page in 22.04.

[image]

1. In the login screen click on your name. **Do not enter the password**.
2. Click on the Gear at the right bottom corner.
3. Select Ubuntu on Xorg

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for all the info. I will start using Wayland once I upgrade to 22.04.1, which comes out in august.

Comment: Strange, I just upgraded and it automatically switched! Well like you said I can change to Xorg

Comment: @AlexFullinator thanks for the feedback. I just checked my desktop Ubuntu 22.04, that I had upgraded from 20.04 many months ago. It was using Wayland. I don't remember switching from Xorg. Maybe I am getting old or the upgrade made the switch. I will edit the answer for future reference..

Comment: Yeah, Canonical made the switch somewhere between 20.04 and 22.04, hence I suppose it’s normal that LTS-only people only noticed when upgrading to 22.04. I tried Wayland at first, but ultimately had to switch back to Xorg… but that’s another matter.

Comment: i do not have gear icon

Comment: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-wayland-on-ubuntu-22-04-desktop