# I have a problem login to my anyDesk remotely

Tags: xubuntu, anydesk

When i try to login to my anydesk remotely in my ubuntu 22.10, it show me that "The session has ended Status: display server unsupported."
And i found this command to solve it "sudo gedit /ect/gmd3/custom.conf" but it shows "sudo: gedit: command not found."
Please help...

Comment: You may want to clarify your question & tags, you've told us the question is about Xubuntu 12.04 but also mention Ubuntu 22.10; please clarify your reason for tags.

Comment: Check if your computer is using Wayland. As far as I know, Anydesk does not support Wayland. Try switching to Xorg.

Comment: See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412624/will-upgrading-to-22-04-automatically-switch-to-wayland/1412627#1412627) for how to switch from wayland to Xorg.

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu 22.10 gnome-text-editor replaces gedit.

You have three options :

1. you can use nano
2. you can use gnome-text-editor
3. You can install gedit back with `sudo apt install gedit`